# jQuery AJAX form post with redirect on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ASP.Net MVC view that submits form data to a controller action.  I'm attempting to use jQuery to post the form via an AJAX call like so:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({                    
          type: "POST",
          url: "/controller/action",
          data: $("#form").serialize()
    });
  });
```

This works great, the form data is posted to the controller just like I want it to.  The problem is that the controller action returns a redirect and after the form is submitted, the browser does not redirect to the location to the url specified in the redirect response.  Using Fiddler, I can see that the controller does indeed return the redirect and that a request is issued for the location specified by the redirect but the browser never actually redirects, the form page is still displayed after the click handler runs.

I've tried adding a success handler to the `$.ajax` call that sets `window.location`.  This works however it seems less than ideal for a couple of reasons.  First, as I don't know how to get the redirect location in the success handler, I have to hard-code the location.  Second, doing the redirect in the success handler actually results in two requests being made to the redirect location.  I'm wondering if there's a better way to get the `$.ajax` call to honor a redirect returned by the server.

Comment: Haven't seen any redirection related code here.

Comment: Why are you using ajax at all? If you want it to redirect, that's the default functionality of a form post to an action page that redirects. simply remove your click event handler and set the action of the form to your controller.

Comment: @KevinB:  We're using AJAX because the native form submit is running into perf problems, presumably due to the large volume of data being posted.  Native form post takes > 30 seconds in Chrome, AJAX runs in subsecond range.  Unfortunately changing the form so that it contains less data is not an option.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.... ajax vs native submit shouldn't happen any faster or slower.

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX request gets the redirect.

You could have your AJAX request return the redirect URL (and not send a `300 Location`), then redirect to that URL in the AJAX success handler.